# Starting jQuery width: 'toggle' with a value of zero

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#logo').hover( function() {
      $('#logo span').stop(true, true).animate({
        width: 'toggle'
      }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
});
```

This takes a span within #logo and animates its width. It's perfect, except that I want the  span to start with zero width and then toggle. I could pass the function another function that toggles the width on page load, but I don't want an ugly flicker when the page first loads.

I've tried adding `width: 0px;` but that completely breaks it.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6WYr/2/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: did you try my latest answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you do this:

```
a#logo span {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

then right after the #logo div in your page, add a script section and do

```
<a id="logo" href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>">m<span>y</span>.lo<span>go</span></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#logo span").hide();
</script>
```

don't wait for document ready as it will fire after.
This should happen quick enough that you won't see it (at least for me it did).

I actually couldn't see the flicker even when using $(document).ready() but YMMV.
Give it a try.

Comment: You see how it jumps right? The OP doesn't want that to happen.

Comment: by the way this seems like a jquery bug. I wonder if there is a ticket for this.. Your original code should work. I just looked into the jquery code and it looks like it doesn't handle the initial state correctly for inline elements in some cases..  We had to use the hide method so it knew what state it was in to start out.

Comment: Hi Matt, that works a treat. Now the only thing I need to fix is the jerky behaviour when you mouseout during the animation!

Answer (score 0):

Would this be acceptable: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKg9r/)**

jQuery:

```
$('#logo span').hide();
$('#logo').hover(
    function(){
        $('#logo span').show(1000);
    },
    function(){
        $('#logo span').hide(1000);
    }
);
```

​Small CSS change:

```
a#logo span {
    display:inline-block;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your effect can be achieve using toggle(), which is what I was using before. I really want it to work exactly as in my original jsfiddle, but with the starting point reversed.